# How to view crawled unicoded arabic string?

Tags: python, unicode, web-crawler

I have crawled some webpages using Python. I ripped off the html tags and only stored some content of those pages as repr(s). Most of those pages are not in English. Now how can I view the crawled content in its original language?

For example, the crawler wrote only one line of some Arabic text to a txt file:
u'\u0639\u0644\u0649'

But when I open the txt file in text editer or browser it looks exactly as above, so it's basically not human readable..

Is there some easy way to render and display the string in Arabic?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you write the text to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x= u'\u0639\u0644\u0649'
>>> open('x.html','w').write(x.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace'))
```

Open `x.html` in a browser and it should display properly.  Actual content:

```
&#1593;&#1604;&#1609;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get human-readable code because you've used repr(s) to write the string to file - and that's what repr is supposed to generate - a programmer-readable representation, which is not entirely human-readable.

If you want to store the text in a format readable by any (unicode-supporting) text editor and browser, you should save it in UTF-8 encoding:

```
import codecs

s = u'\u0639\u0644\u0649'
f = codecs.open('output.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Make sure you set your browser or editor encoding to UTF-8 if it doesn't get auto-detected.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print ast.literal_eval("u'\u0639\u0644\u0649'")
على
```

Well, not the order shown in the browser, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway I can convert the string back to HTML so that I can view it in browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print u'\u0639\u0644\u0649'
على
```

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested it is not a bad idea to view the file in a browser.

- Store it in utf-8 (like `open('x.html','w').write(x.encode('utf-8'))`), as most browsers are well equipped to handle utf-8.
- In the browser, you may need to change View->Character Encoding to Utf-8.
- You will need Arabic fonts on your machine, so the browser can use these to display the characters.

Having written this, any file viewer/editor that is capable of decoding utf-8 and has access to the fonts can do this for you (e.g. vim works fine on my machine).